# Different logging times on Windows XP and Windows 10

Tags: c++

I'm working with a software that can run in Windows XP and 10, it is built with visual studio compiler v110_xp.

Performing a cycle that normally would last 45 seconds, I recorded different times:

- on XP a cycle lasts 45 secs with or without log
- on 10 a cycle lasts 45 secs without log and 48 with it

I analyzed the different log files and I discovered that on Windows 10 there are many small intervals (about 16 milliseconds), about 5 times the number of intervals found on Windows XP.

The log function can be summarized as:

```
BOOL LogMessage(CString fName, CString Msg) {

    EnterCriticalSection(&LogMsgFileCritSec);

    FILE *ff = fopen(fName, "at");
    BOOL ret = FALSE;

    if (ff) {
        char date[40];             
        struct _timeb timebuffer;

        ( ... )

        fprintf(ff, "%s.%03hu - %s\n", date, timebuffer.millitm, Msg);

        fflush(ff);

        fclose(ff);

        ret = TRUE;
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection(&LogMsgFileCritSec);

    return ret;
}
```

This function is used by multiple thread but the threadsafe methods do not affect time (tested).

So I could say that the real causes of the delay on Windows 10 are only the functions fopen, fprintf, fflush and fclose (tested disabling them).

I can't understand why this behavior. Do you have any suggestions?

Do you have any ideas to improve this feature?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you dont have to open/close the file for each single log message. btw for code reviews there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Just make sure to post complete and working code there.

Comment: XP is _ancient_. 10 may have more protections or some other thing that's causing a bit of a slowdown, particularly in a critical section, and particularly when you're opening & closing the file _every single time_ (!). I don't know the answer but... does it really matter? Is there value in analysing the dark recesses of a long-obsolete operating system? Do we even know enough about the different pieces of hardware & storage to tell from here?

Comment: (I miss when an OS needed only 64MB RAM to run *sniff*)